# Ghostscript 9.23 flattening of PDF annotations

Tags: ghostscript

Prior to Ghostscript 9.21, annotations could be flattened into the document using the following code:

```
c:\gs\gs9.23\bin\gswin64c  -dSAFER -dDOPDFMARKS -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE 
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3
-sFONTPATH=c:/gs/fonts;%windir%/fonts;. -sPDFPassword= 
-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dPassThroughJPEGImages=true 
-sOutputFile=file_noPW.pdf  file.pdf
```

This would make an annotations permanent to the file, much like Acrobat's preflight option.  As of version 9.21, this no longer happens.

Is there a way to flatten the annotations?  I use this to make sure pdf's that are imported using latex have all the annotations present, as pdflatex and xelatex do not import annotations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its always worth reading the documentation. If you look [here](https://ghostscript.com/docs/9.54.0/VectorDevices.htm#PDF) section 7.4, PDF file output, you will see the PreserveAnnots switch described.

Comment: I was looking through the Use document, not the High Level Output devices.  Thank you very much!

Comment: The link in this answer is outdated. Please add more context to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be there now: https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/VectorDevices.htm

Comment: I added this option but the annotations are gone, any clue as to why?

Comment: @YanKingYin are you trying `-dPreserveAnnots=true`? I was trying same :) but after reading up documentation (link provided by @sdive above) it turns out it works the other way. Try out with `-dPreserveAnnots=false` instead as this is actually meant to meant to work the way you intend: "_you can set this switch to false which will cause all annotations to be inserted into the page content stream, instead of preserved as annotations_"